# Create column that shows previous earned salary (groupedBy)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, window-functions, data-wrangling

I'm trying to build a replacement for the `.shift()` function of Python. I'm pretty close, but need the final touch to make everything work. This would be implementing a right form of `GroupBy`.

I have a dataframe like this one:

| month | userid | amount | counterparty_iban |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John Jones | 2400 | ENG12345 |
| 4 | John Jones | 1200 | ENG12345 |
| 8 | John Jones | 2300 | ENG12345 |
| 5 | John Jones | 3000 | AM12345 |
| 9 | John Jones | 5000 | AM12345 |
| 12 | John Jones | 6000 | AM12345 |
| 1 | Joe Jones | 1200 | AM12345 |
| 2 | Joe Jones | 2400 | AM12345 |
| 3 | Joe Jones | 5000 | AM12345 |

I need to change the dataframe above to the format of the table below:

| month | userid | amount | counterparty_iban | previous_salary |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John Jones | 2400 | ENG12345 | null |
| 4 | John Jones | 1200 | ENG12345 | 2400 |
| 8 | John Jones | 2300 | ENG12345 | 1200 |
| 5 | John Jones | 3000 | AM12345 | null |
| 9 | John Jones | 5000 | AM12345 | 3000 |
| 12 | John Jones | 6000 | AM12345 | 5000 |
| 1 | Joe Jones | 1200 | AM12345 | null |
| 2 | Joe Jones | 2400 | AM12345 | 1200 |
| 3 | Joe Jones | 5000 | AM12345 | 2400 |

Here is the code to create the input dataframe:

```py
columns = ["month", "userid", 'exactoriginalamount', 'counterparty_iban']
data = [("1", "John Jones", "2400", 'ENG12345'),
        ("4", "John Jones", "1200", 'ENG12345'),
        ("8", "John Jones", "2300", 'ENG12345'),
        ("5", "John Jones", "3000", 'AM12345'),
        ("9", "John Jones", "5000", 'AM12345'),
        ("12", "John Jones", "6000", 'AM12345'),
        ("1", "Joe Jones", "1200", 'AM12345'),
        ("2", "Joe Jones", "2400", 'AM12345'),
        ("3", "Joe Jones", "5000", 'AM12345')]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data, schema=columns)
```

I've been trying numerous applications with the following code:

```py
w = Window().partitionBy().orderBy(F.col('userid'))
df = df.withColumn('previous_salary', F.lag('exactoriginalamount', 1).over(w))
```

However, I somehow need to groupby "userid" and "counterparty_iban" so that the different "previous_salary" column displayed the right data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to properly describe partitions. In the example output, I see that you want to make partitions (windows) based on "userid" and "counterparty_iban". The function `lag` will be run in these partitions separately. In the script below, I also used `cast("long")` for the "month" column, as using your code the column "month" is originally created of type string (ordering by string column would return different sort order than ordering by number).

```py
w = Window.partitionBy("userid", "counterparty_iban").orderBy(F.col("month").cast("long"))
df = df.withColumn("previous_salary", F.lag("exactoriginalamount").over(w))

df.show()
# +-----+----------+-------------------+-----------------+---------------+
# |month|    userid|exactoriginalamount|counterparty_iban|previous_salary|
# +-----+----------+-------------------+-----------------+---------------+
# |    1| Joe Jones|               1200|          AM12345|           null|
# |    2| Joe Jones|               2400|          AM12345|           1200|
# |    3| Joe Jones|               5000|          AM12345|           2400|
# |    5|John Jones|               3000|          AM12345|           null|
# |    9|John Jones|               5000|          AM12345|           3000|
# |   12|John Jones|               6000|          AM12345|           5000|
# |    1|John Jones|               2400|         ENG12345|           null|
# |    4|John Jones|               1200|         ENG12345|           2400|
# |    8|John Jones|               2300|         ENG12345|           1200|
# +-----+----------+-------------------+-----------------+---------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

from pyspark.sql.window import *

custom_window=Window().partitionBy(["userid"]).rowsBetween(-1, -1).orderBy(["month"])

df = df.withColumn("previous_salary", max(df.amount).over(custom_window))